# meaning of the word "woozy"

Tags: word-usage, meaning

When you say "I feel woozy" or "You look woozy", what does the word "woozy" exactly mean? "dizzy" or "absent-minded"?

Thank you!

Comment: What has your research shown?

Comment: My question is closed now. But i'm asking Mr. Davo. Sorry, but I can't understand your question, "What has your research shown?" What do you mean by that? would you please rephrase your question for me to understand? For your information, I'm not a native speaker of English.

Comment: We expect users to have made a basic investigation first - looked at a dictionary, done an internet search - that sort of thing - to demonstrate that they have attempted to find the answer on their own before asking us to do so,

Comment: Oh, I got it now. Thank you for your advice. Actually I looked up the dictionary first to get the exact meaning of the word "woosy". But it was so confusing to me because sometimes it seemed to mean "dizzy", other times "blank minded(?)", etc. So I wanted to know what image comes to their mind first when native speakers hear that word 'woosy'. What about you, Mr. Davo? What image do you get first when you hear that word?  Thank you for your concern:)

Comment: The image I get first is dizzy and disoriented, like if you have motion sickness or get drunk. But next time, please include that evidence of research and that specific question (I understand this, is it right?) in your question. :)

Comment: Ok, I will. I got it. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dizzy refers, mostly, to the spinning sensation such as is experienced by spinning round and round too quickly. Woozy, by contrast, is a similar but less specific kind of disorientation, such as what one might feel after too much alcohol, or perhaps after receiving a bump to the head.

I've never heard woozy being used to mean absent-minded. However, "dizzy" can be used as a synonymy for "stupid", the most common example probably being the "dizzy blonde" (which is, of course, a completely unjustified stereotype).

Comment: Your answer is so clear and helpful for me. Thank you. Have a nice day~ By the way, 'dizzy blonde' means usually 'idiotic blonde', right? But 'the unfairly stereotypical dizzy blonde' you mentioned  means 'a very smart girl' even though she is not as smart as Einstein? Am I correct?

Comment: The phrase _dizzy blonde_ or _dumb blonde_ (that's dumb in the American sense of stupid, not mute) was used to stereotype pretty, blonde girls as not being very bright. Of course this is unfair, as there is no relation between intelligence and appearance.

Comment: I didn't get you, Ms. Bunting. Would you teach me again? So you mean that 'the unfairly stereotypical dizzy blonde' is still 'a dumb blonde girl'? And 'someone of less than Einsteinian levels of intelligence' means NOT 'someone who is not as smart as Einstein but still smarter than average persons' BUT 'someone who is not smart at all'? I'm asking the meaning of  'someone of less than Einsteinian levels of intelligence'.

Comment: My apologies. There is probably a technical name for my use of "someone of less than Einsteinian levels of intelligence", but it was unnecessarily confusing here!  My intended meaning was exactly what Kate said. I've clarified (I hope!) In the answer.